# Every almost periodic function is uniformly continuous

Tags: functional-analysis

I know that weakly almost periodic functions an a locally compact group are uniformly continuous. But I do not know how to prove it. Would you please introduce a good reference to me? Thanks.

Comment: My answer was not appropriate here. Deleted.

Comment: @saghar : can you perhaps provide a definition of what you are talking about, or a hyperlink?  I have done some work with almost periodic functions on $\mathbf{R}^n$, but I have never even heard of weakly almost periodic functions on any domain.  Also, the title of your question does not contain the word "weakly", so it may not match your question.

Answer (score 0):

**Reference:** [Weakly Almost Periodic And Uniformly Continuous
Functionals On The Fourier Algebra Of Any Locally
Compact Group](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1974-189-00/S0002-9947-1974-0336241-0/S0002-9947-1974-0336241-0.pdf)

Comment: I am talking about weakly almost periodic functions not periodic ones.

Comment: Thanks. But it is not a good reference since it is about dual of a group and dual of a locally compact group is not necessarily a group. I need the proof for functions on the locally compact group.

Answer (score 0):

This is **Theorem 13.1** of Eberlein's classical paper:

*Eberlein, W. F.*, [**Abstract ergodic theorems and weak almost periodic functions**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1990424), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 67, 217-240 (1949). [ZBL0034.06404](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0034.06404).